# Add php code to css

Tags: php

I have php string with css code. And I want to add php value to css code ( $main_color ). So I try:

```
$css = $css . "
    .main{ color:<?php echo esc_attr($main_color);?>; }
";
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: `echo` it inside your CSS `style` tag. Also why are you trying to echo inside `PHP`? Just concatenate the variable.

Comment: $css .= "     .main{ color:".$main_color." } ";

Comment: You're making this harder than it should be. You also should be getting a parse error here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest PHP tags like that; you need to concatenate the values:

```
$css = $css . "
    .main{ " . esc_attr($main_color) . "; }
";
```